# anyLogic – BPMN model import as xml or bpmn file

Tags: anylogic

I have a BPMN model as xml and bpmn file and would like to simulate the process flow in anyLogic. I’m using the PLE version of anyLogic.

Is it possible to import a simple BPMN model as xml or bpmn file in anyLogic? And if yes, do you have an idea how to realize this?

As a result, for example, I imagine getting the base of the process flow as elements of the bpmn model in anyLogic.
I would then add parameters and other settings in anyLogic, since they are not part of the BPMN model. Thank you!

Comment: Get in touch with Gerd Wagner, he doesa lot of BPMN stuff with AnyLogic: https://www.linkedin.com/in/gerdwagner/ (feel free to drop my name and link to this post)

Comment: Thanks Benjamin for your hint! I read Gerd Wagner's papers and he has also interesting approaches to combine both.

Answer (score 0):

no there's nothing publicly available to do that, maybe someone has done it but not AnyLogic.... Also it's not like all BPMN software works the same way... Some BPMN software have customized interruptions for instance.

In this case, I pretty much think you are on your own to achieve it... but often I use BPMN models and build them from scratch in AnyLogic or I do the opposite and use BPMN for communication purposes after AnyLogic is done.

Comment: Thank you Felipe for your insight! This will probably be my approach now as well.